# no matter what the user inputs the output stays at 2000

Tags: java

1) Change the program so that the user has to enter the initial balance and the interest rate. Assume that the user will enter interest rates in whole numbers ("5" would represent an interest rate of 5%, for example). Assume that the user will enter initial balances that are numeric only - no commas. 2) Change the code to display how many years it takes an investment to triple.

I have entered my scanner so the user can input their balance and interest. no matter what user enters it outputs 2000.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class InvestmentRunner
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Please Enter Initial Balance:");
  String Balance = in.next();
  System.out.print("Please Enter Interest Rate:");
  String Interest = in.next();

  final double INITIAL_BALANCE = 10000;
  final double RATE = 5;
  Investment invest = new Investment(INITIAL_BALANCE, RATE);
  invest.waitForBalance(2 * INITIAL_BALANCE);
  int years = invest.getYears();
  System.out.println("The investment doubled after "
        + years + " years");


  }   
}
```

Comment: does it work as it should? then you are on the right track...

Comment: `StackOverflow` isn't a venue for reassuring people with low self-esteem... (SO is, afterall, a subset of the Internet).  It's for posting questions with specific problems and seeking solutions to those specific problems.  Keep plugging away at it, and come back when you run into an actual problem.

Comment: well no matter what the user inputs the output stays at 2000

Comment: @user2934105 Then your question should ask about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the question askers comment: `well no matter what the user inputs the output stays at 2000`

These are the lines in which you're constructing an `Investment` object, calling methods on this object, and then printing the value.

```
Investment invest = new Investment(INITIAL_BALANCE, RATE);
invest.waitForBalance(2 * INITIAL_BALANCE);
int years = invest.getYears();
System.out.println("The investment doubled after " + years + " years");
```

You haven't posted the `Investment` class, so I just have to assume these methods are fine.  The PROBLEM is here:

```
final double INITIAL_BALANCE = 10000;
final double RATE = 5;
```

These are the variables you're sending to the `Investment` constructor.  Constants you've hardcoded in.  Meanwhile, this is where you take user input:

```
System.out.print("Please Enter Initial Balance:");
String Balance = in.next();
System.out.print("Please Enter Interest Rate:");
String Interest = in.next();
```

You take the `Balance` (should be `balance`), then take `Interest` (should be `interest`), then you do nothing with these values.  You need to parse a `double` out of these `String`s and then send them as the arguments to your constructor.

Comment: I can't really provide much more of an answer without doing the entire assignment for him...

Comment: no that is all i needed to know thank you.

Comment: @user2934105 For the sake of your `StackOverflow` account, I'd recommend editing your question to improve it to actually asking what I answered here, and then marking this answer as the accepted answer.